# getting ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2) when working with tensor flow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

Getting following error when i run my object detection python script

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection_tutorial.py", line 25, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.55.78.100.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.55.78.100.dylib**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had a similar core error (i.e. the string `(which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)` also threw me for a loop), there was a bug in the specific build of the Python library I was importing.

Try importing an older build/version, but if that doesn't work a simple re-install of the python flavor you're using (via homebrew) might be a quick fix.